# Call notifyDataSetChanged() on other list fragment/tab

Tags: android, android-listfragment, notifydatasetchanged

I have add three list fragments on activity.

1. Contact list fragment
2. Tasks list fragment
3. Bookmarks list fragment

Users can bookmark items on Tab1 and Tab2 and then it displays in Bookmark tab/fragment.

i want to know, while bookmarking on Tab1 or Tab2, how can i call notifyDataSetChanged() for Bookmarks fragment to refresh listview.

Can i get listAdapter associated with other list fragments to refresh listview items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to achieve that

**Way 1:**

You have to implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` in your activity for the `ViewPager` and on

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // get the instance of the listview from the fragment and refresh it.
}
```

refresh the listview.

And a preferable way

**Way 2:**

Use `EventBus` [link.](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

`compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'`

only you have to `post` and `register` data. It will do all the things.

The sender or receiver may be `Activity`, `Fragment` or any `Background threads`.

Answer (score 0):

You need an observer pattern on this. 
Tab1 and tab2 will broadcast a message and Bookmark tab/fragment will listen to that message and notify accordingly

from Tab1 and Tab2 you can trigger broadcast message via:

```
EventsListeners.getInstance().broadCastEvent(ListenerCategory.CATEGORY_BOOKMARK, ChangeEvents.EVENT_UPDATE, null);
```

In Bookmark tab/fragment you can implement an interface "EventObserver" and override the method "broadCastEvent"

```
@Override
public void broadCastEvent(ListenerCategory tabType, ChangeEvents event, Bundle data) {
    if (tabType == ListenerCategory.CATEGORY_BOOKMARK) {
        if (event == ChangeEvents.EVENT_UPDATE) {
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      // call notify datasetChanged
                  }
              });
        } 
    }
}
```

You also have to register the listener in the same activity or fragment:

```
public void registerListeners() {
    EventsListeners.getInstance().registerListeners(this, ListenerCategory.LISTENER_BOOKMARK);
}

public void unRegisterListeners() {
    EventsListeners.getInstance().unRegisterListener(this, ListenerCategory.CATEGORY_BOOKMARK);
}
```

ChangeEvents.java

```
public enum ChangeEvents {
EVENT_UPDATE;
```

}

EventObserver.java

public interface EventObserver {

```
public void broadCastEvent(ListinerCategory tabType, ChangeEvents event, Bundle data);
```

}

EventListeners.java

```
public class EventsListeners {

private static EventsListeners commonListeners = null;
private EventListener[] listenersArry = null;

private EventsListeners() {
    this.listenersArry = new EventListener[ListinerCategory.values().length];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.listenersArry.length; i++) {
        this.listenersArry[i] = new EventListener();
    }
}

public static EventsListeners getInstance() {
    if (EventsListeners.commonListeners == null) {
        EventsListeners.commonListeners = new EventsListeners();
    }
    return EventsListeners.commonListeners;
}

public void registerListeners(EventObserver listener, ListinerCategory type) {
    this.listenersArry[type.ordinal()].registerListener(listener);
}

public boolean contain(EventObserver listener, ListinerCategory type) {
    return this.listenersArry[type.ordinal()].contain(listener);
}

public void replaceRegister(EventObserver listener, ListinerCategory type) {
    this.listenersArry[type.ordinal()].replaceRegister(listener);
}

public void unRegisterListener(EventObserver listener, ListinerCategory type) {
    this.listenersArry[type.ordinal()].unRegisterListener(listener);
}

public void unRegisterAllListener(ListinerCategory type) {
    this.listenersArry[type.ordinal()].unRegisterAllListener();
}

public void broadCastEvent(ListinerCategory type, ChangeEvents event) {
    this.listenersArry[type.ordinal()].broadCastEvent(type, event);
}

public void broadCastEvent(ListinerCategory type, ChangeEvents event, Bundle data) {
    this.listenersArry[type.ordinal()].broadCastEvent(type, event, data);
}

public void destroyObject() {
    for (final EventListener element : this.listenersArry) {
        element.destoryObject();
    }
    this.listenersArry = null;
    EventsListeners.commonListeners = null;
}
```

}

ListenerCategory.java

```
public enum ListinerCategory {

CATEGORY_BOOKMARK;

public static ListinerCategory get(int index) {
    return ListinerCategory.values()[index];
}
```

}

Comment: First of all thank you for such explanatory example. I have implemented Observer pattern. It works fine but when i try to update UI (in Observer update method) with Toast message or notifyDataSetChanged(); it throws error. It seems update method doesn't work on UI.

Comment: Yes. The exception in this case would be regarding only the original thread that created the ui and change itself. You can resolve this by following code snippet:

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    // notify ui
            }
        });

Comment: I have updated the answer. See if this works for you.